# MySQL Import 4GB+ SQL on MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, import

I’m trying to import a 4GB+ SQL to MySQL 5.6 (64-bit) on Windows 7 (64-bit)

The problem is I after a few seconds (), get this message:

```
ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 204: MySQL server has gone away
```

It does import, but it only the first 3 tables (the first 2 and the 3rd table just the structure.

I’ve been trying this command:

```
mysql -u root -p firedb < C:\database_2013-11-12.sql
```

I tried a lot of things I could find here on stackoverflow with no success yet:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table
max_allowed_packet=2048M
wait_timeout=3600
net_read_timeout=3600
net_buffer_length=3600
```

The SQL file was created on “MySQL 5.1.72-2-log (Debian)” using this command:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases
```

I have also tried setting --max_allowed_packet when running the command like this:

```
mysql --max_allowed_packet=2048M -u root -p --all-databases
```

Comment: Once you have changed all the settings in my.ini/my.cnf did you restart the MySQL service?

Comment: Hi. Yes I restarted the MySQL, and checked with SHOW VARIABLES to make sure it sset as in the ini

Answer (score 0):

The [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html) states:

> The most common reason for the MySQL server has gone away error is
> that the server timed out and closed the connection.
> By default, the server closes the connection after eight hours if
> nothing has happened. You can change the time limit by setting the
> wait_timeout variable when you start mysqld. See Section 5.1.4,
> “Server System Variables”.
>
> If you have a script, you just have to issue the query again for the
> client to do an automatic reconnection. This assumes that you have
> automatic reconnection in the client enabled (which is the default for
> the mysql command-line client).

So i would start with increasing the timeout.

And if this does not help read int he attached documentation link for the rest of reasons for server has gone away error.